# How to create a variogram

Tags: r, mapping, kriging, covariogram

I'm a new user of R, which I use in my studies in digital soil mapping. I have my data, as you can see in my .csv file. There are columns SN (sample number), SAND, SILT, CLAY, OM (Organic Matter). I am trying to create a variogram for each property. Specifically, one variogram for clay, one for silt, one for sand, and one for organic matter.[csv file with data]

Any ideas of how I can accomplish this?[image: csv with data]

I want to create the variograms for each soil property, and then execute Kriging in R, in order to make maps.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?  Also, a screenshot of the data is not ideal - if you can use `dput(yourdata)` you will get a format that can be pasted into your question here.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Rhank you for your comment. I have tried the following:

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen a prompt of my R code:  # Next step is to create a variogram
#In the function of variogram the variable i chose and the data file are
contained in the parenthesis.
pr.v <- variogram(Augers$pH ~ 1, Augers)
pr.vf.exp <- fit.variogram(pr.v, vgm(0.013,"Exp", 0.35, 0))
# So, now, we 're going to plot the variogram using the function plot
plot(pr.v, pr.vf.exp)
# If we want, we can chge the point characters in the variogram with the
function pch , and the color to (e.g) red 
plot(pr.v, pr.vf.exp, pch =20, col ="red")

Comment: thanks - can you edit those into your original question so they get formatted nicely please?

Comment: I've found this walkthrough of the approach in general (variograms and kriging) using the packages `gstat` and `sp` https://gsp.humboldt.edu/olm/R/04_01_Variograms.html which may help.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Good evening.

Thank you very much for answering me. I have also seen this link you provided I just can't match my data to the example it gives. Can you help me?